# PHP How to know how long a person stayed on the website

Tags: javascript, php, time, timer

Is there some function/method to know how long a person stayed on my website? 'cause there's a form where you just should have 5 seconds to fill it. So I was wondering if I could get the time that a person stayed there.

Like:

```
if($time > 5){ echo 'It took you more than 5 seconds. Let's try again'; } else { #code... }
```

I wouldn't like do this in javascript because people could edit it.

Comment: Yeah, use the `$_SESSION` var. On load add a timestamp, in js count down using that timestamp (so the user understands they have 5 seconds to fill it out). On submit check current time with one stored in session.

Comment: It makes sense, also with Unix time you don't need to perform mathematical operations too complex, just need to subtract those variables. Thank you! :)